# count findAll records in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to find all records from user table except one user type. i.e. I have a user table `dec_user` where there is an attributes `user_type`. I want to find all records except `user_type` `9`. Then I'll count the number of rows. So, I wrote as:

```
$user_type = 9;
    return count(User::model()->findAll(array("condition"=>"':user_type' != $user_type")));
```

Actually, I do not understand how to write this condition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not need to retrieve an array from database and count it using the PHP `count()` function.

The Yii way:

```
return User::model()->count('user_type <> '.$user_type);
```

or by using params:

```
return User::model()->count('user_type <> :type', array('type' => $user_type);
```

or, if you want to build the SQL query, use commandBuilder:

```
return Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
            ->select('COUNT(*)')
            ->from('user')
            ->where('user_type <> '.$user_type)
            ->queryScalar();
```